# AWS Cognito vs IAM role in Android APP for security aspects

Tags: android, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

An app of mine in the android playstore (let's say >1.000.000 installs) collect some anonymous statistics. I want to store and work with these statistics on an amazon EMR cluster.

Currently I use AWS Cognito for creating Unauthorized access for Uploading the data to S3/Firehose. For saving money I thought of changing this procedure to use a hardcoded IAM user, which only able to upload the data to FH/S3. I don't need the identification of each user.

What disadvantages should I expect in terms of security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognito federated identities is 100% free. Switching to an IAM user won't save you money.

Per the pricing page: "Using the Federated Identities feature for authenticating users and generating unique identifiers is always free with Amazon Cognito."

Answer (score 1):

I think if they somehow get access to your sourcecode they can upload data to s3/firehose . Actually I am in the same kind of dilema only I dont have an app on appstore yet but since the IAM i am using only has read access to a AWS service I dont really see issue with it. because If I am correct AWs does charge for every token refresh after 50.000 MAU if you use Cognito

Comment: But when someone get access to my source code he is also able to use cognito federated user to upload data. Jeff is seems to be right: Federated Identities are always free.

Comment: Yes, Jeff is right for sure, but I still see no advantage on using cognito even if its free. With using cognito you have to make a lot of more connections (from device site) than using a dedicated IAM user.

Comment: @mly how do you mean alot more connections ?